# git not connecting to remote server

Tags: git

We have a remote origin in git, and I'm unable to push or pull, which occurred suddenly after trying to change the remote domain to something else, and then changing it back. The messages from git seem to contradict.

When I push, I get the following error. It says 'unable to connect to :' and then there is a blank, which would tell me the domain is not set.

```
$ git push origin
fatal: unable to connect to :
[0: ::1]: errno=Connection refused
[1: 127.0.0.1]: errno=Connection refused
```

However, the remotes are correct:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git://my.domain.com (fetch)
origin  git://my.domain.com (push)
```

In the .git/config:

```
$ more ../.git/config | grep domain
    url = git://my.domain.com
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: It looks like some problem in your DNS or network setup. Can you access the host that has the repository by other means? The `::1` and `127.0.0.1` are IPv6 and IPv4 localhost addresses respectively, which is why I suspect DNS problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should the result of a `git remote -v` look like this?

```
origin  git://my.domain.com/reponame (fetch)
origin  git://my.domain.com/reponame (push)
```

In which case it may be an idea to remove and recreate your remote

```
git remote rm origin

git remote add origin git://my.domain.com/reponame
```

Comment: Same result - The lack of something after the 'connect to:' makes me think something is flawed. Good suggestion though, I didn't know that.

    
$ git remote rm origin
    $ git remote add origin git://my.domain.com:REPO
    $ git pull
        fatal: unable to connect to :
        [0: ::1]: errno=Connection refused
        [1: 127.0.0.1]: errno=Connection refused

Comment: You were close - the colon should have been a slash - git remote add origin git://my.domain.com/reponame, can you change your response to reflect that?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why mine uses the `:` seperator there. Must be a `gitolite` peculiarity. Made the change for posterity.